# Create an electrical installation plan in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to document my electrical installation neatly in Latex and TikZ. A normal TikZ drawing is no problem so far, but I would like to add something like switches, sockets, etc. to a given background (my house floor plan) in a coordinate system at defined locations.

In the example picture, I added a symbol at the point x = 2700mm / y = 1700mm.

At the same time, I would like to give this element a unique name and display further documentation in the form of a normal LaTeX list/table.

Is there a way to define some kind of function for this?

Pseudo code
AddElement(ID: 123, type: PowerSupply, x-cord: 2700, y-cord: 1700, usage: ChildrenRoom, other information....)

And the result is then the shown picture and below the picture there is something like a textual summary:

- ID: 123, type: PowerSupply, x-cord: 2700, y-cord: 1700, usage: ChildrenRoom ....

[image: Floor Plan]

**EDIT**
Now I created a MWE. Let's say image-a is the Ground Floor and image-b is a power supply I want to put on there.

Right now, I'm at this point:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[a4paper,left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=10mm]{geometry}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{courier}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\scalebox{1.7}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node (ground_floor) at (current page.center){\fbox{\includegraphics[width=99mm,height=107.4mm]{example-image-a}}};

\node [draw=red, scale=0.05] (label) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image-b}};

\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Ground Floor}
\end{figure}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

This MWE generates the following output:
[image: Example]

Questions:

1. How can I set the caption below the image while using overlay setting in TikZ?
2. How can I set my coordinate system to start (0,0) from the top left of the image-a?
3. How can I rescale the coordinate inputs with the same scaling factor my scale box uses?

Comment: You can define a macro, pic or shape.  Shapes are the hardest (`\pgfpathlineto` etc) but can have predefined anchor points.

Comment: Hmm could you have a look on my Edit? I tried to add a MWE :)

Comment: @PascalS, you can open your plan in a viewer, select, copy and paste it into your question. Then we can download it under your filename. So you can replace the example-image ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of answering your questions, I focus on achieving the result in a reasonably way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin=0.2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
PowerSupply/.pic={
\node[opacity=0.2] {\includegraphics[width=1cm, height=1cm]{example-image-b}};
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (100,0) (0,-100) -- (0,100) (-100,-100) arc[radius=100, start angle=-90, end angle=90];
\draw[red, ultra thick] (0,0) circle[radius=200];
},
}
\begin{document}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.0025cm, y=-0.0025cm, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (ground_floor) {\includegraphics[width=17.5cm, height=25.1cm]{example-image-a}};
\tikzset{shift=(ground_floor.north west)}
\node[fill=red, circle, minimum size=10pt] {};
\draw[red, ->, line width=2pt] (-200,0) -- (7200,0);
\foreach \x in {1000,2000,...,7000} \draw[red, line width=2pt] (\x,-100) --node[black, above=10pt]{\x mm} (\x,100);
\draw[red, ->, line width=2pt] (0,-200) -- (0,10200);
\foreach \y in {1000,2000,...,10000} \draw[red, line width=2pt] (-100,\y) --node[black, left=10pt]{\small \y mm} (100,\y);
\pic at (2700,1700) {PowerSupply};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Full page image with a scale and a small diagram]

Comment: WOW, this is amazing! So simple and still very powerful! I will accept this answer and create a new question for my open questions! Thanks!